# How to Restrict Windows software to specific directory?

Tags: windows, security, virtual-machine, virtualization, sandbox

Imagine I have an untrusted software which Do Not Want to access any directory except the one I specify (Restrict software access to an specific directory)

Is there a way other than ([Virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine) & [Sandbox](https://help.comodo.com/topic-213-1-517-8257-.html) ) to do this ?

Comment: Windows 10 has a feature that might do what you want, but you have eliminated, the best options to do what you want.  Either way software recommendations are out of scope

Comment: @dsstorefile but software can still access my files and folders on drives and etc

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not looking after a software to do this. I want to know that if there is a way to do so and whats that called.

Comment: Only way is with software...

Comment: @Ramhound What's the software category name ?

Comment: @dsstorefile That's a great Idea you said, Although malware apps can still be harmful as they can infect windows drive !

Comment: @dsstorefile as I mentioned in the Question "Is there a way other than (Virtual machine & Sandbox ) to do this ?"